# Keras with variable input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to build the model that should take two inputs with **variable lengths**:

```
env_input1 = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')
env_input2 = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')
env = concatenate([env_input1, env_input2])
env = Dense(50, activation='relu')(env)
env = Dense(100, activation='relu')(env)
env = Dense(50, activation='relu')(env)
env_output = Dense(1)(env)
env_model = Model(inputs=[env_input1, env_input2], outputs=[env_output])
adam_opt = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
env_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam_opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have variable length inputs for an Artificial neural neural network, as the 1st Dense layer in the network wouldn't know the **dimensions of the weights** to be initialized before training.

But in case of Convolution neural networks you may have variable image dimensions at input as all the input parameters in case of `Conv2D` decide the dimension of weights. We later use **Global Average Pooling** in case of CNNs to successfully add a Dense layer classifier after CNN feature extractor.

Comment: Or You can only have one dimension that is not static